# Scope of register value

Tags: scope, dalvik

if i have some dalvik bytecode like this:

```
const/16                        v0, 0
const/16                        v1, 255
:goto23
if-ge                           v0, v1, goto42
const/16                        v1, 0x23
# [...] more code here
add-int/lit8                    v0, v0, 1
goto                            goto23
```

would the if-ge in line 4 always check for v0 < 255 or would it check after the first round for v0 < 0x23? The question is: do have registers scopes in dalvik? I don't think so, but i'm not sure at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "scope" of a register is the containing method. Once a register is set, any subsequent read within that method will use that value, until the register is set to a different value.